# What is the Pearldiver?

Tags: proof-of-work

I've frequently heard the term "Pearldiver" around Iota. What exactly is it and what does it do?

Comment: @Helmar too broad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"PearlDiver" is the name of the algorithm doing the PoW in the IRI.
You can find the code in the official repo on github [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/hash/PearlDiver.java).

Comment: the name of the Java reference implementation of this algorithm, to be more precise.